# YTDL-CORE NODE.js music. How to get a video title. Undefined var

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, discord.js

With this code:

```
for(var i = 1; i < (server.queue.length); i++) {
                            var songtitle
                            YTDL.getInfo(server.queue[i], function(err, info) {
                                songtitle = info.title;
                            });
                            list += `\n${i}. <${server.queue[i]}>`
                        }
                        message.channel.send(list);`enter code here`
```

the var `songtitle` is always undefined.
I tried a lot of diferent things but still I don't know why `songtitle` is always undefined.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when trying to run this code? Usually those pesky things tell you what the error is.

Comment: no song title is just undefind somehow...

Comment: I did debug this thing and songtitle should be something

Comment: I'm sure you did, but without you telling us what you've done to debug, what the results of that debugging were, and providing a little more than "this code doesn't work," we're pretty limited in how we can help. Checking for errors is a pretty obvious first step. Have you checked what `info` actually is in the callback?

Comment: Try ending every command with a semicolon. `var songtitle` lacks it. And other commands too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is a callback problem, specifically when it comes to sync vs async code which you can learn more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659116/node-js-sync-vs-async). To fix this, try putting the rest of your code *within* the callback instead of outside of it. Here's an example of a fix using [async and await](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/) as the ytdl-core module [now supports promises](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/commit/b10dae8a660bd164b6c33d49552db1ddc2a1a53f):

```
// Must be called within an async function.
for (var i = 1; i < (server.queue.length); i++) {
  var info = await YTDL.getInfo(server.queue[i]);
  var songtitle = info.title;
  list += `\n${i}. <${server.queue[i]}>`
}
message.channel.send(list);
```