# How to run synchronous execution in node js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run synchronous execution in node js is there any way to do that other than using events and Async because those didn't work for me?

```
 for (i=1; i < response.payload.parts.length; i++) {
     if(response.payload.parts[i]!==undefined && response.payload.parts[i].filename!==undefined) {
         console.log("5")
         myEmitter.emit('trah', auth, 'me', response.id, response.payload.parts[i].body.attachmentId, response.payload.parts[i].filename,response.payload.parts[i].mimeType);
     }
}

var ul = fs.readdir('content/'+response.id,(err) => {
    if(err) { console.log(err) }
})

console.log("9")

if(ul!==undefined) {
    console.log('mahiech lehné')

    for (var i=0; i<ul.length; i++) {
        if(mime.getType(ul[i]).substring(0,5)==='image') {
            console.log("10")

            // console.log(te)
            te+='<a href="http://localhost:3000/content/?id='+response.id+'&atch='+ul[i]+ '"><img border="0"  src="http://localhost:3000/content/?id='+response.id+'&atch='+ul[i]+'" width="100" height="100"></a>'
       }

       console('11----'+i)
       fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/test.txt',te)
   }
}
}
fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/test1.txt',te)
console.log("12")
res.end(buildres(te))
```

This my 'trah' event

```
myEmitter.on('trah', (auth,userId,messageId,id,name,type) => {
    gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
            auth: auth,
            userId: userId,
            messageId: messageId,
            id: id},
        function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            if (!res) {
                console.log('no resposnse found')
            }
            if (res===undefined) {
                console.log('No messages found.');
            }
            if (res) {
                console.log("6")
                if(type.substring(0, 5)==='image'){
                    res.data = res.data.replace(/_/g, "/");
                    res.data = res.data.replace(/-/g, "+");
                    console.log("7")
                    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/content/' + messageId + '/'+name,res.data,'base64',(err)=>{console.log(err)})
                }
                else {
                    console.log("8")
                    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/content/' + messageId + '/' + name, utf8.decode(base64.decode(res.data)),(err)=>{console.log(err)})
                }
            }
        })
});
```

this is the execution order i get since my execution is depentdent on each ordered statement i can't get it to work right
1
2
3
4
5
9
12
6
8

Comment: You can't do that.  You should use promises.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions and answers here on stack overflow about how to sequence (one after the other) asynchronous operation in node.js.  You really ought to go find and read a whole bunch of those.  It is a very common thing to have to learn when starting out in node.js.

Comment: either they are really hidden well or they don't serve what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Most of the file system calls have a synchronous equivalent. For example, sync version of `fs.readdir` is `fs.readdirSync`. Refer to the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

While you CAN call the synchronous versions of these functions, it is not really recommended. Refer to this post for more info on why: [Node.js sync vs. async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659116/node-js-sync-vs-async)

Comment: i'm forced to do them synchronously because like i mentioned above some of the expressions are dependent on the previous expressions in order to get the wanted result and i know about the equivalent versions of the fs.* and the fs.*sync but my fonctions are made i'm looking for a way to make them synchronously them too

Comment: "i'm forced to do them synchronously because like i mentioned above some of the expressions are dependent on the previous expressions". This is not true, you can still do async. Read about promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: i have spended the last day trying to apply the promise on my code but couldn't do it an exemple would very much appreciated

Comment: brian glaz i already tried with promises but still no results the executions still happens after :/