# Difference between hash() and hashSync() functions of BCrypt package of NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passwords, bcrypt, password-hash

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const hash = bcrypt.hash(<myPassword>, 12)

const hashSync = bcrypt.hashSync(<myPasword>, 12)
```

What aspects do they possibly differ in, and Could they be used interchangeably?
(Detailed explanation very much welcome and greatly appreciated!)

Comment: For a quick understanding, I have logged the values of both 'hash' and 'hashSync' for the value 'myPassword':

`hash:  Promise { <pending> }` and
`hashSync:  $2b$12$xEpu8E8s0FGIC2wgYbacSO.KoMBQSEoOoobHxv3uWU.h/amo99Wg6`

Comment: And that's exactly what it does. Non-sync version returns a promise instead of a direct value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js sync vs. async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659116/node-js-sync-vs-async)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***hashSync*** is used to Synchronously generates a hash for the given string. It returns the hashed string

***hash*** is used for Asynchronously generating a hash for the given string. It returns promise is callback is committed and you need to resolve the promise.

> refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs#hashsyncs-salt

Answer (score 5):

bcrypt.hash takes a callback as its third parameter which will be called when the hash is completed.
bcrypt.hashSync runs the hash, waits for it to complete and returns the hashed value.

In other words "hash" is asynchronous and hashSync is synschronous.

Answer (score 1):

you mean

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const hash = bcrypt.hash(<myPassword>, 12) // this returns a promise 

const hashSync = bcrypt.hashSync(<myPasword>, 12) //this on is sync so it stops every line of code after untill it's executed
```

read [this](https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/) article to know the difference between sync and async